# Graph JSON response seldom contains raw HTML

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I send batch request made of calendar appointment request to Graph API, I seldom encounter a improper response from the API: some XML are injected as is in the JSON response.
This is impossible to unserialize, so I cannot know which appointment had issues, and it leaves no choice but to reiterate the same calendar appointments batch, which poses performance issue.

The request to batch API looks as follow (I intentionally hide information with *** in the post data below and did not show with ... the 3 others requests to calendar Graph API)

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "33",
            "method": "PATCH",
            "url": "/me/calendars/***/events/***",
            "body": {
                "subject": "***",
                "location": {
                    "displayname": "***"
                },
                "body": {
                    "content": "***"
                },
                "categories": ["***"],
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2021-05-12 06:00:00",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2021-05-12 07:00:00",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "showAs": "free",
                "isReminderOn": false,
                "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 0,
                "singleValueExtendedProperties": [{
                        "id": "String {***} Name ***",
                        "value": "***"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }, {
           "id": "34",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I seldom get (before and later on, the same id worked just fine)

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "33",
            "status": 503,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=us-ascii"
            },
            "body":<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
        }, {
            "id": "34",
            "status": 200
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Could you please investigate this issue and render a proper JSON response in any case, even if it fails with a 503 response?

Note: I reported this bug at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/12951 but none of the solution provided by the automated closing message was relevant.

Comment: HTTP 503 tells that the service is unavailable. I would suggest you to try the following in such scenario... (1) Re-try the API call (2) Outside of your code, check the same graph api call in POSTMAN/Graph explorer to see if it works or not.

Comment: Batching is complex one, so you need to slice the calls into smaller API calls and try tagging one by one, which will help you to isolate the issue and find which call is leading to the issue. Also make sure that when you do PATCH/update calls the destination object is not modified by others (someone else in the given org or the backup/archive solutions), which will end up in errors as well.

Comment: Hi Dev, thanks for your answer, this is not due to the slicing (I respect the limitation of 4 appointments per batch) and this is not due to this particular appointment id because it works most of the time for the same id before this fail and after this fail, plus another id can seldom fail (one fail over a thousand of trials without any concurrency).
I understand there can be rare issues with the service (the API can also rarely and inconsistently answer with 504 responses but the response is at least well formatted), I am just asking whether the Graph response can be well formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rather reported the bug to the right github repo https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-serviceissues/issues/93